# flutter_blue does not detects Bluetooth device after building release APK

Tags: flutter

```
flutter_blue: ^0.7.2
```

flutter_blue works fine in debug mode and detects and scans for available Bluetooth devices but does not detect Bluetooth device after building the release APK

says `Bluetooth device not found`

Comment: Could it have anything to do with permission?

Comment: I have added the permissions required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe catches an error in the release mode, please use this command for getting apk:

1. `flutter clean`

And then

2. `flutter build apk --no-shrink`

And also you can use this command `flutter run release` for debugging in the release mode

Comment: thank @ abbas jafary :) I am looking into it

Comment: you're welcome, my friend @JaveedIshaq if you get your answer please upvote and check my answer (-;